# Hibernate.getClass(Object proxy) returns Class, how to get Class<T> instead?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, proxy

My Problem is with Hibernates `getClass(Object proxy)` method which according to documentation does help me

> [to g]et the true, underlying class of a proxied persistent class.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#getClass(java.lang.Object)

The `getClass(Object proxy)` methods returns a `Class` object. The `getClass()` method of objects however returns on the other hand a `Class<?>` object.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--

This difference composes a difficulty to me when working with methods that employ Java generics like this

```
public <T`getClass(Object proxy)`> T doWithGenericObject(Class<T> clazz)
```

which cannot be used with the information that `Hibernate.org` provides me via its `static Class Hibernate.getClass(Object proxy)` method.

Is there:

1. a way to get the `Class<T>` from hibernate? or
2. a way to convert `Class` to `Class<T>`? or
3. prevent Hibernate to retrieve a Proxy in the first place?

Comment: I'm probably safe to say that there's no way to get Hibernate to give you non-proxied class that would be particularly useful, since that library relies on proxies to do its job.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov So I understand that the option "3. prevent Hibernate to retrieve a Proxy in the first place" is not possible? 
Well then I kind of need to get Hibernate.getClass() to give me `Class <?>`. Maybe somebody can hence provide an answer

Comment: Can you further explain why you bothered so much by absense of wildcard in your type? Any parametrized type that is used without its type parameter (`Class`) is logically equivalent to the widest bound that type parameter can have (in your case, `Class<?>`). So the two are almost identical. You can cast it to the desired type if you want, like `(Class<MyObj>) Hibernate.getClass(new MyObj())`, that will only give you compile warning.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov thank you. 
As already hinted at in the question above, the reason is Java generics. A methods with generics like this method signature for example: `public <T> T methodName(Class<T> type)` will not allow you to provide the return of `Hibernat.getClass(proxyObject)`. 
Compile-time casting is not an option. It is possible to do `(SomeObjectClass) obj.methodName(Hibernate.getClass(proxy))` but in this case I need to know `SomeObjectClass` in the first place and hence could simply used
`obj.methodName(SomeObjectClass.class)`.
The point is to do the getClass genericly at runtime.

Comment: Hmm. But if you have `public <T> T method(Class<T>)`, the actual erased type of `T` is Object, so at runtime you will lose that information anyway, and you can't have any `T` other than `T==Object`. On the other hand, if `T` is `T extends MyType`, then you can do `(Class<MyType>) getClass(proxy)`, if you know that proxy has that type. Passing actual class into a method is actually pretty valuable - I know of several frameworks that benefit from inspecting class metadata or have some cache of handlers bound to classes.